# Devise current_user is not a User instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Rails 6.0.3.2 with devise 4.7.2

In my tests I encounter a unexpected error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: User(#47437210347680) expected, got #<User id: 1, email: ...> which is an instance of User(#47437198887480)
```

Using `byebug`, indeed current_user isn't a User instance !

```
(byebug) current_user.class.__id__                                                                                                                                                            
47437198887480                                                                                                                                                                                
(byebug) User.__id__                                                                                                                                                                          
47437210347680
```

So my association `@contest.users << current_user` fails...

Interesting things, if I reset my databases I do not have the issue at the first try when I run my tests !

I founded that [open issue on gitlab](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37591) but no workaround.

Thanks a lot for your help on that !

### Edit

Here is my association between users and contests

```rb
# contest.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Contest < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

```rb
# user.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contests
end
```

I noticed the problem occur after editing files in the app/ directory. I can edit my test files without causing this issue. So I suspect a reload of classes done somewhere that makes this divergence...

Comment: Are you associating contest with users?

Comment: Hi @hashrocket ! I edited the post.

Comment: Did you add `user_id` to your `contests` table?

Comment: As it is a N*N relationship, I have this join table
```
create_table "contests_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.bigint "contest_id", null: false
  t.bigint "user_id", null: false
end
```